# Return observable and set value in the same method with angular

Tags: angular, typescript, http

I want a service that would return the observable and set a value to field in the same method.

Now my `userService.getUserDetails()` method looks like this:

```
private requestUrl: string;
private bic: string;
private id: string;
private name: string;

getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
this.bic = 'aaa';
this.id= '123';

this.requestUrl = `${configs.api}v1/bics/` + encodeURIComponent(this.bic) + `/ids/` + encodeURIComponent(this.id) + `/users`;

const userObservable = this.http.get<User>(this.requestUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));

userObservable.subscribe(data => this.name = data.name);

return userObservable;
}
```

I want to do two things when `getUserDetails` is called: 
1) return `Observable<User>`
2) set the `name` value so I could access it later in other classes by injecting this service in constructors, without calling the http request again. I think I want to have something like this:

```
  getName() {
return this.name;
 }
```

So I'm not sure about the subscribe, because I'm getting undefined after try to use the value. What is the best approach here?

Comment: You shouldnt return the observable if you subscribe to it, since its a subscription now. What do you get in your logs if you do `userObservable.subscribe(data => console.log(data));`? Observables are asynchronous, which means you should only work with the variable once the observable returned a value.

Comment: So what do you suggest?

Comment: I wrote it up for you in an answer, feel free to ask any questions if you're unsure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the observable like this:

```
   public name: string;
   public bic: string;
   public id: string;
   public getUserDetails(): Observable<User> {
        this.bic = '...';
        this.id = '...';
        this.requestUrl = `${configs.api}v1/bics/` + encodeURIComponent(this.bic) + `/ids/` + encodeURIComponent(this.id) + `/users`;

        return this.http.get<User>(this.requestUrl).pipe(catchError(this.handleError));
    }
```

Ideally, this method is in a service and does nothing else but to return the observable and do error-handling if needed.

In your component you could have this:

```
    constructor(private readonly _yourService: YourService) {}

    public ngOnInit(): void {
    this.getUserDetails();
    console.log(this._yourService.name) // can be undefined, since the observable is asynchronous and probably isnt finished yet
    }

    public getUserDetails(): void{
    this._yourService.getUserDetails().subscribe(
    data => {
    this._yourService.name = data.name;
    // start doing other things, this.name should be defined, if your service returned the data correctly.
    }
    )
    }
```

Alternatievly, you can also do all of this in your service, it's really your choice of design.

Comment: You see the problem is that I don't want to call the http request twice. The scenario that I want is: 1) I open the page, it calls `getUserDetails`, it returns the Observable(I really need the observable) and also sets the name variable. 2) Later I call this service and get the assigned variable not calling the http request for the second time. Is it even possible to do something like this?

Comment: You can alternatively store the variable in your service for later use, this calls the http request once and assigns `name` once its done. If you dont want getUserDetails() to be called again you can also store a bool in your service that serves as a check if the function has already been called and conditionally call the method in `ngOnInit()`

Comment: So yes, the question is how do I store the variable after calling the http request, so I can use it later?

Comment: I've updated the answer again, it does now store the fetched name in the service, where you can access it from any component.

Comment: Thanks, I'm not sure if I understand it, because the workflow should look like this. `MainComponent` calls the `userService.getUserDetails`(it returns the observable and stores the name variable). Later on `anotherService` needs the stored name variable from the `userService` without calling `userService.getUserDetails` for the second time. I'm not sure if we understand each other, but thanks for taking your time

Comment: Hm, the other service can just access the stored variable in the user service, should be easy as that. Assuming your component has called the getUserDetails() method once.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211856/discussion-between-developer1-and-mike-s).

Answer (score 0):

use "tap", in your service

```
name:any;
const userObservable = this.http.get<User>(this.requestUrl).pipe(
tap((res)=>{
    this.name=res;
}),
catchError(this.handleError)
);
```

Sometimes it's used a kind of "cache"

```
name:any;
const userObservable = (this.name)?of(name):
  this.http.get<User>(this.requestUrl).pipe(
    tap((res)=>{
      this.name=res;
    }),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
```

So, you always can subscribe to the function, the first time, make the call to http, the second use the value of name  -`of(name)` return an observable